# How to think about the Cartesian product in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

I'm beginning to study category theory, and I encountered this result:

> In any category with a terminal object 1, any object X is itself a Cartesian product of X and 1. (Halvorson, p. 34)

This certainly clashes with the set-theoretic view of the Cartesian product of two objects (sets in that case) being an entity of a higher rank, and thus non-identical with either of these objects. So, my question is: how to think about Cartesian products in the category theoretic setting?

Comment: They mean that $X$ is **a** product of $X$ and $1$, and this is trivial to check using the definition of a product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)). Don't confuse it with **the** cartesian product of sets, which provides **a** product in $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks, that's clear now.

Comment: Sorry I should not post answers as comments, in particular when I always complain about that when others do it :D. I copied the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean that $X$ is **a** product of $X$ and $1$, and this is trivial to check using the definition of a [product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)). Don't confuse it with **the** cartesian product of sets, which provides **a** (possibly different, but isomorphic) product in $\mathbf{Set}$.